# Scrollbar is visible but scrolling is not working (y-axis)

Tags: css, tailwind-css, overflow

I know there are threads already about this but my overflow-y-scroll is not working and I can't seem to figure out why ...

The scroll bar is visible on the right side but when scrolling the wheel nothing moves.

Can someone take a look into this simple code sample and see if there is something I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance

```
<div className="pointer-events-auto fixed top-0 right-0 z-[100000] max-h-screen w-96 overflow-y-scroll bg-gray-700 px-6 pt-60">
       <div className="h-[20vh] overflow-y-scroll text-white">
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
              <p className=" py-5">Content to make parent overflow</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I seems to work fine- https://play.tailwindcss.com/vyy8XWeocu?size=230x192

Comment: @Akshay thanks for the demo in this playground. I don't understand why in my project it is not working. I am using a scroll library (locomotive scroll), my guess is the problem might be situated there ...

Comment: You should post the code.